# Workaround to show Chatter with Private sharing model

Tags: apex, chatter

Is there any alternative way to show Chatter feed on an object(JobOrder) which is marked as Private in sharing settings?

We got around the record access restriction by displaying records using vf pages but we also have to show chatter feed to our external clients(Customer community users) for this object. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

> Chatter feed cannot open up the record access which has been marked as Private in Sharing Settings.

So, first you need to write a sharing rule and give a `Read Only` access to Customer Portal Users.

Secondly, to expose the feed to external users, only those posts which have been shared by `All with access` can be viewed by Customer Portal users.

[image: all with access]

**Update based on comments**

Refer [Sharing a Record Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

**Creating Apex Managed Sharing for Customer Community Plus users**

> Customer Community Plus users are previously known as Customer Portal users. Share objects, such as AccountShare and ContactShare, aren’t available to these users. If you must use share objects as a Customer Community Plus user, consider using a trigger, which operates with the without sharing keyword by default. Otherwise, use an inner class with the same keyword to enable the DML operation to run successfully. A separate utility class can also be used to enable this access.
>
> Granting visibility via manual/apex shares written to the share objects is supported but the objects themselves aren't available to Customer Community Plus users. However, other users can add shares that grant access to Customer Community Plus users.

Comment: The client did not want the community users to view each other's records and that is the reason for making the sharing model Private. Is there any other way out?

Comment: you can write apex managed sharing to expose the record to the portal users

Comment: I realised that customer community users are not recognised as valid users, so had to switch to using VF pages which worked great. I am stuck with enabling chatter feature now..

Comment: Our context here is 'customer community' users not plus users. I tried this, coded the trigger and realised only when i was testing ..https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AQ15IAG - refer to this link please. VF pages with extension controllers solved the purpose, just have to show Chatter